# Inappropriate value for attribute "notification_channels": element 0: string

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-stackdriver, terraform-provider-gcp

While creating google_monitoring_alert_policy, I keep getting the following error

Inappropriate value for attribute "notification_channels": list of string required.

here is an excerpt from

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "activeplaceworkspace_email" {
  count        = length(var.notification_email_addresses)
  display_name = "DevOps Alerts on ${element(var.notification_email_addresses, count.index)}"
  type         = "email"
  labels = {
    email_address = element(var.notification_email_addresses, count.index)
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "disk_alert_policy" {
  display_name = "${var.prefix} - Disk utilization, sda1 (80%)"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "${var.prefix} - Disk utilization, sda1 (80%)"
    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used\" resource.type=\"gce_instance\" metric.label.\"device\"=\"sda1\" metric.label.\"state\"=\"used\" metadata.user_labels.\"type\"=\"web-server\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 80
      trigger {
        count = 1
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period   = "60s"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
      }
    }
  }
  notification_channels = [
    google_monitoring_notification_channel.workspace_email.*.id,
    "google_monitoring_notification_channel.workspace_slack.name"
  ]
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "notification_email_addresses" {
  description = "Email addresses to be notified."
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
    "a@mail.com",
    "t1@mail.com",
    "da@mail.com",
    "23@mail.com"
  ]
}
```

**What Works?**

if take only one

```
  notification_channels = google_monitoring_notification_channel.activeplaceworkspace_email.*.id
```

But two or multiple notification channel values do not work with `[]`, I think the main issue is with `[]`.

Comment: In which resource do you use `notification_channels` and how?

Comment: @Marcin, I've updated the answer, I am using it in google_monitoring_alert_policy, please acknowledge, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current use of `notification_channels` creates a list containing a list and a string in the form of:

```
notification_channels = [list, string]
```

Instead it should be a list of strings, which you should be able to obtained using [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/concat.html) method:

```
  notification_channels = concat(
    google_monitoring_notification_channel.workspace_email.*.id,
    [google_monitoring_notification_channel.workspace_slack.name])
```

Comment: now it says, Error: Error updating AlertPolicy "projects/activeplace-staging/alertPolicies/8285073275262611175": googleapi: Error 400: Field alert_policy.notification_channels[1] had an invalid value of "google_monitoring_notification_channel.workspace_slack.name": Channel name must be of the form "projects/{project_id_or_number}/notificationChannels/{channel_id}".

Comment: This can be resolved by removing double quotes